# Unable to get rid of border around hr tag in ExtJS javascript page

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I have an ExtJS web application in which I have several hr tags.  The problem is that the lines are rendered with a border around them no matter what I do - whether I specify a border-style of hidden or none - a border still shows up.

Here is my code

```
var newForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    header: false,
    monitorValid: true,
    height: 390,
    width:800,
    layout: new Ext.layout.FormLayout,
    forceLayout: true,
    padding: 5,

    items: [ {
                html: "<hr>", style: 'display: block;margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-style: hidden;'
             }
     ]
     });
```

And it produces the following:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this difinition

```
items: [
    {
        // Actually you add panel
        // xtype: 'panel',
        html: "<hr>",
        style: 'display: block;margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-style: hidden;'
    }
]
```

you add `Ext.panel.Panel` to your `Ext.form.FormPanel` items (because of [`defaultType`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-cfg-defaultType)).

When you apply `style` you actually add it to this `Ext.panel.Panel` DOM element, not your `<hr>` element.

You have to add style to `<hr>` difinition

```
html: "<hr style='display: block;margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-style: hidden;'>"
```

[Here is simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14q0)

Comment: I actually tried that before.  Ironically, it took out everything BUT the border.

Comment: Hmmm, can you update provided fiddle to reflect issue? Also try to setup `panel` with `border: false`.